# My Ubuntu Nautilus is not showing the shortcuts and drives in list view

Tags: nautilus

The file manager on my system is not working and not showing shortcuts. It looks like this:

[image: thumbnail view]

I want to see the file manager like this:

[image: list view]

How can I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

**To see files as a list...**

1. Click on the "Toggle View" button in the header bar of Nautilus, towards the right side.

[image: Nautilus Toggle View Button]

**To show the side bar (i.e. the "Shortcuts")...**

1. Click the "hamburger" menu (with three horizontal bars) at the right side of the header bar.
2. Click Preferences
3. The Preferences dialog will open.
4. On the Views tab, check-mark "Show sidebar"
5. Close the Preferences dialog

[image: Nautilus Preferences]